# Copy file from Windows Desktop to Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi

I'm using Putty SSH client to connect to my Raspberry Pi (w/ Raspbian) from my windows 10 computer. Now that I'm in, I'd like to be able to copy my file from my windows computer's desktop called `file.txt`, to my Raspberry Pi's desktop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an SCP client to transfer the files. It is not embedded into the PuTTY graphical client, but you can run a command-line tool [`pscp.exe`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) distributed with PuTTY.

Open the command-line on the Windows machine and run the following (assuming `file.txt` is in the current directory):

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe" file.txt pi@your_pi:Desktop/
```

It will transfer the file to the `Desktop` directory inside the home directory of the user `pi`.

Answer (score 0):

A suitable way would be to set up a vsftpd server using `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`. Then use a windows ftp client to connect and transfer that way.